# Error al usar la función sqrt de la librería math

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
d = 8
e = 2
from math import *
print(sqrt(d**e))
```

Y el resultado obtenido es: **16.88210319127114**, el resultado obviamente no es correcto.

Ahora lo que noté es que la importación de la librería math no estaba al principio y lo reescribí así:

```
from math import *
d = 8
e = 2
print(sqrt(d**e))
```

Y así efectivamente obtengo: **8.0**

Mi pregunta es: ¿Por qué sucede esa discrepancia en el resultado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una de las muchas razones por las que usar wildcard (`from modulo import *`) es una muy mala práctica a la hora de importar.

Cuando usas este método de importación, toda función, clase, variable global, ... disponible en el módulo importado pasa a agregarse al espacio de nombres global actual.

**`e` (Número de Euler - base del logaritmo natural) es una constante definida en el [espacio de nombres del módulo `math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.e)** y por tanto es importada desde el mismo al usar `from math import *`. En el primer ejemplo, al importar todo el contenido de `math` después de declara tu variable `e`,  `math.e` solapa a tu variable `e` por lo que pasa a valer 2.718281828459045:

> √8 ** 2.718281828459045 = 16.88210319127114

sería equivalente a (de forma mucho más legible):

```
import math

d = 8
print(math.sqrt(math.e ** d)
```

En el segundo caso, como importas antes de definir tu propia `e`, es tu variable la que solapa a la proveniente de `math`, por lo que el resultado es el esperado.

No uses `from modulo import *` a no ser que quieras de forma consciente y deliberada solapar espacios de nombres (que es para lo que está básicamente pensado) o en algunos contados casos muy particulares. Incluso así, suele ser mala practica incluirlo en código en producción. En su lugar debes hacer:

```
import math

d = 8
e = 2
print(math.sqrt(d**e))
```

o bien:

```
from math import sqrt

d = 8
e = 2
print(sqrt(d**e))
```

Además de evitar solapamientos indeseados y sus consecuentes errores, ambas formas son mucho más legibles y explícitas, ambas cualidades muy valoradas en el entorno Python (ver [zen de Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)):

> - Explícito mejor que implícito
> - La legibilidad cuenta
> - Frente a la ambigüedad, evitar la tentación de adivinar.
> - Los espacios de nombres son una gran idea, ¡tengamos más de esos!

Aparte de generar código menos legibl, de los solapamientos indeseados y de que no sabes con exactitud que estás importando, terminas poblando el espacio de nombres actual con un montón de cosas que seguramente no vas a usar.